# how to resolve "TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of null"

Tags: qt, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I'm a new qml programmer and I found my self in this problem that when I want to call a new page when clicked on a button it says:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of null
```

I've tried everything I know to resolve this but still nothing.

Here is my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1
import "components"

MainView {

    objectName: "mainView"

    applicationName: "com.ubuntu.developer..EcoLover3"

    automaticOrientation: true

    width: units.gu(48)
       height: units.gu(60)
    PageStack {
        id: pagestack
       Component.onCompleted: push(page0)
        Page {
            id: page0
            title: i18n.tr("Bem Vindo à aplicação do EcoLover" )
            visible: false
            Text {
                id: entrada
                text: qsTr("Caro Cliente, <br>aqui poderá contrloar os seus gastos de energia</br>")
            }
        Column {
            anchors.margins: units.gu(3)
                            spacing: units.gu(3)
                            anchors.fill: parent

           Image{
               anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
           source: "/home/diogo/ecoLover_teste2/components/Ecolover_com_stroke.png"
           }

           Button {
               anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
               text: i18n.tr("Page one")
               onClicked: pageStack.push(page1, {color: UbuntuColors.orange})
           }
           Button {
                             anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                             text: i18n.tr("Entrar no  EcoLover")
                             onClicked: pageStack.push(Qt.resolvedUrl("Pagina_inicial.qml"))
                         }
            }
        }

        Page {
                   title: "Rectangle"
                   id: page1
                   visible: false
                   property alias color: rectangle.color
                   Rectangle {
                       id: rectangle
                       anchors {
                           fill: parent
                           margins: units.gu(5)
                       }
       }
     }}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a small mistake in naming your Pagestack component:

```
PageStack {
    id: pagestack
```

Later you're calling it with `pageStack.push`. To work correctly you just need to rename your component id (with a capital **S**):

```
PageStack {
    id: pageStack
```